Angular SSR generates browser and server folders on build. Can I use the site as static or with server-side rendering after configuration?
After setting up and running with SSR, Angular initially renders on the server.I'm on angular version 18.1.0
After the initial load, Angular takes over and the application operates as a Single Page Application (SPA) using Client-Side Rendering (CSR). I'd like to confirm if I can use the site as a static application or with continuous SSR after the initial server-side rendering.
Imagem ssrStatic

It depends on how you implement it.

As JSON Derulo (love that nickname btw) says it depends on how you implement your code. If using Angular router (ie with RouterLink) to navigate between pages, the browser will keep doing client side rendering by using Angular's JavaScript code to navigate. Otherwise, if using href on <a>nchor elements to navigate to pages, the browser will request to the server that URL, therefore triggering a server side render. I'd say the usual way is to use the Angular router unless there's a very specific use case requirement.
